# How do I add a blob to Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I created a storage account on Windows Azure. Then I added a container called `rubicon` to my storage account and got to the following screen:

[image]

I don't see any button/link that allows me to add a blob. Would be nice to see a "*Click here to add blob*" link on this page, but there is nothing. I did have a look on [How to use blob storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs-20/), but that only shows how do do it though code.

Where do I add a blob on the Windows Azure portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portal does not have the capability to upload blobs in a container. You would need to use one of the many available storage explorers to upload files in the blob container. Do a search around and you'll find open source/free/commercial storage explorers.

Comment: There is a list of storage tools at http://storagetools.azurewebsites.net/.  Some do more than storage, some all storage types and others just BLOBs.  Pick out what works best for you.

Comment: Which tool would you recommend?

Comment: I think it depends on your requirement. If you're looking for a free tool just to manage blobs, I would recommend Azure Explorer from Cerebrata (I may be a bit biased here as I was part of this company :)). If you're looking for a free tool which manages blobs, tables and queues, I would recommend Azure Storage Explorer. But you should certainly try Azure Management Studio from Cerebrata.